# What are the modern day applications of pc 16550 UART, is it still widely used in the industry?

Tags: uart

Just started with learning LINUX serial port driver development and came across pc16550 UART.

Considering the fact that UART is now mostly integrated in SOC or MCU, was just wondering if 16550 is still widely used in the industry.

Answer (score 4):

The UART itself not, but because of existing software, it makes it easier if a uart *behaves* like a 16550.

When I was developing a UART for an ASIC, I was asked by my boss to make it 16550 compatible.

All I had to do was adapt the control registers and map the bits and addresses to the same location as on the 16550. Then move all the others extra features to some registers which do not exists on the 16550.

It worked indeed direct with the standard Linux driver. That saved *a lot* of time in bringing up Linux as SW people like to use printk for debugging.

Comment: The 16550 has a software gotcha due to the priority interrupt mechanism; I have seen a couple of occasions where an interrupt was taken but another interrupt occurred during the interrupt handler. If the interrupt bit is true but not polled at exit from the handler, no further interrupts will ever be generated.